# Finding the Page-ID of my Woocommerce Main Shop Page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am looking to set styling specific to my Woocommerce Main Shop Page. Right now when I try to make css changes to the shop layout, they take place on all pages. I have researched and found that I can use method such as the follow:

```
<?php
$myaccount_page_id     = wc_get_page_id( 'myaccount' );
$shop_page_id          = wc_get_page_id( 'shop' );
$cart_page_id          = wc_get_page_id( 'cart' );
$checkout_page_id      = wc_get_page_id( 'checkout' );
$terms_page_id         = wc_get_page_id( 'terms' );
?>
```

Is this accurate?
Do you have a better suggestion?
Where do I run this php if this is the best option?

Comment: How you do the changes on the shop that affect the whole layout? Please update your question

Comment: My question is to find the Page-ID of the Woocommerce main shop page; so although that is cool info; it does not matter

Comment: so `$shop_page_id          = wc_get_page_id( 'shop' );`is the right code, as described in WC docs.

Comment: Thank you!! Where do I put this?

Comment: You said: My question is to find the Page-ID of the Woocommerce main shop page; so although that is cool info; it does not matter .

That's how you get it.

Comment: Telling me where to place that = Teaching me how to find page ID

Comment: Telling you how CSS affects the entire page /= Teaching me how to find Page ID

Answer (score 0):

You can add a CSS body class to your main shop page via the `body_class` filter:

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'add_body_class_to_main_shop_page', 10, 1 );
function add_body_class_to_main_shop_page( $classes ) {
    if ( is_shop() ) $classes[] = 'shop-page';
    return $classes;
}
```

The example above will add the CSS class `shop-page`. You can then base your other CSS on that.